# Fine tuning PID controller for non-linear closed-loop system

Tags: pid-controller, rotor

I am having trouble getting my PID controller to be accurate over a range of values. My goal is to input a duty cycle for a PWM wave, which controls the speed of a fan rotor. The range of possible speeds should be 300RPM to 2700RPM.

Currently the PID controller is achieving accurate speeds when 800 to 1600 RPM is requested, but below those speeds the output is too high, and above those speeds the output is too low. I think this may be because the relationship between duty cycle and rotor speed is not entirely linear.

Here is our current PID equation:
duty_cycle = [ speedset + control + 735] / 4300
Speedset is the requested speed, control is the PID control variable, and the constants are from the equation that we found to be mostly accurate for linking duty cycle with output speed (it is however a linear equation, and was not entirely accurate for extremely low and high data points).

The control variable is: control = 0.104*error + 0.104*previous_error + 0.13*next_error

This is my first time working with PID, so please correct me on anything I am doing wrong. Does anyone have any advice for how I might improve the accuracy of the system at very low and very high speeds?

[image: Block diagram of the system]

Comment: What is your error signal?  (what is it's definition: speed - speedset?)

Comment: Could you provide a control block diagram? Have you tried running it open loop with no load?

Comment: error = requested speed - actual speed.
I can draw up a code block diagram a bit later when I have time, at a group meeting right now.
What do you mean with no load? Without the rotor?

Comment: Provide a block diagram with all the elements in your system

Comment: I've added in the block diagram one of my group members created :)

Comment: Are you talking about a motor Driving a fan or an integral motor fan combination such as a small muffin fan.  Are you sure your motor can provide enough torque to overcome the intertia of the fan rotor?  How about providing some specs on your fan and motor IE model #s?

Comment: Why have you implemented a feed forward controller (poorly)

Comment: "below those speeds the output is too high... above those speeds ... too low" - how _much_ too high and too low? ('too high', 'too low', 'not accurate' are meaningless terms without a magnitude). What range of speeds do you get if you just set the duty cycle from 0 to 100% without feedback?

Comment: If you're not calculating an error, you're not doing proportional control.

Comment: Why do you call this a 'PID' controller? I don't see any indication that you actually have those 3 elements - **P**roportional, **I**ntegral, **D**erivative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, everyone. I believe I have found and answer by simply adding a conditional that can identify different operating regions (low speed, medium speed and high speed) and uses a different PID equation for each. This has solved the problem.